# Computing Factor Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I am reading John Fraleigh's *First Course in Abstract Algebra*, $\S$36 on the Second Isomorphism Theorem which says that if $H < G$ and $N \triangleleft G$, then
$$(HN)/N \cong H/(H \cap N).$$
He then goes on with an example which I delineate for easy reference:

1. Let $G = \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z,$ and subgroup $H = \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \times \{0\},$ and normal subgroup $N = \{0\} \times \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z.$
2. Then clearly $HN = \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ and $H \cap N = \{0\} \times \mathbb Z \times \{0\}.$
3. We have $(HN)/N \cong \mathbb Z$ and we also have $H/(H \cap N) \cong \mathbb Z.$

I am comfortable with (1) and (2), I am familiar with definition of factor group but how do you break down that $(HN)/N$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$ and $H/(H \cap N)$ is isomorphic to $ \mathbb Z$ in (3), please?

Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: I hope this isn't a stupid question, but I don't understand what $HN$ means, even though I've looked around everywhere. I'm also trying to get my head around these isomorphism theorems!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In, (HN)/N, anything in the HN of the form (a,x,y) is going to end up in same equivalence class (here 'a' is fixed whereas x and y can vary). You can verify that using the definition of equivalence classes modulo N.

This shows that the equivalence classes modulo N, i.e. (HN)/N is determined by the first element in the 3-tuple of HN. The isomorphism between (HN)/N is trivial where each element (a,b,c) is sent to 'a' in $\mathbb Z$.

Similarly, in case of  H/(H $\cap N$)$\cong$$\mathbb Z$, every element of the form (a,x,0) is sent to the same equivalence class (where 'a' is fixed and x may vary). Hence, there is a clear isomorphism between H/(H $\cap N$)$\cong$$\mathbb Z$ where each element (a,x,y) is sent to 'a' in $\mathbb Z$.

I hope that helps

Comment: Thank you. I think your response is the one, I get it now.

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to help. Good Luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is a general fact that, given groups $G_1,\ldots,G_n$ and normal subgroups $H_i\trianglelefteq G_i$,
$$(H_1\times\cdots \times H_n)\trianglelefteq(G_1\times\cdots\times G_n)$$
and that
$$(G_1\times\cdots\times G_n)/(H_1\times\cdots\times H_n)\cong (G_1/H_1)\times\cdots\times (G_n/H_n)$$
For example, in your situation,
$$\begin{align*}
(HN)/N&=G/N\\
&=(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})/(\{0\}\times\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})\\
&\cong(\mathbb{Z}/\{0\})\times(\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z})\times(\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z})\\
&\cong\mathbb{Z}\times(\text{trivial group})\times(\text{trivial group})\\
&\cong\mathbb{Z}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Does the downvoter care to comment?

Comment: Because you did't right edit! $H \cap N = \{0\} \times \mathbb Z \times \{0\}.$

Comment: @2000: That error was in the original post - my goal was merely to improve the formatting. I didn't notice the typo, nor did I introduce it, so please don't blame me for it.

Comment: @ZevChonoles : Thank you! I think I am comfortable with $\mathbb Z / \{0\} \cong \mathbb Z$, but perhaps I haven't internalized the definition of factor group good enough, I am lost when you said $\mathbb Z / \mathbb Z$ is trivia group. Could you please break it down, and thanks again.

Comment: $\mathbb Z / \mathbb Z = \{\mathbb Z\}$, a group containing one element.